# Javascript arrays: merge 2 arrays with priority

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

How to merge two arrays of different lengths and the values of the shorter array should have priority over the larger array's values, but the result should still have the length of the larger array. Please look closely how I arranged the two arrays below:

```
var short  = [[ 25,12],          [576, 12],          [576,584],          [ 25,584],          [ 25,12]];
var long   = [[301,12],[400,192],[602,230],[461,380],[487,584],[301,497],[115,584],[140,380],[301,12]];
// --------------------as suggested by the above
var result = [[ 25,12],[400,192],[576, 12],[461,380],[576,584],[301,497],[ 25,584],[140,380],[ 25,12]];
```

In the example above it seems the length of `long` is twice compared to `short`, but it should work even if it's triple in size or just one element longer.

Comment: It seems the replacement elements are correlated to the difference in length of the arrays (the longer array is twice as long so the shorter array replaces every second element). Will the length of the longer array always be an integer multiple of the length of the shorter array?

Comment: Start by defining the logic in plain English, than it will be easier for everybody (including yourself) to understand, and solve

Comment: @RobG - the sample data itself doesn't fit your rule of integer multiple

Comment: @RobG: nop, as I said, the longer array could be from 1 element longer, to any kind of multiplication or addition.

Comment: @Amit—the OP hasn't said what the logic is, I just guessed in the hope of getting more information. Without that, any answer is a guess.

Comment: @thednp—so any random replacement of elements of the longer array is fine, just so long as all the elements of the shorter array are there and the length isn't changed?

Comment: The arrangement is clear when the number of elements in the long array is a perfect multiple of the number of elements in the short array, but you have not explained what should happen it it is not a multiple, for instance when the long array has just 1 more element. In that latter case, which one element of the long array will ***not*** be replaced?

Comment: Yes @RobG, another thing is, I wish for the replacement to happen for closer inner array's values. I will update the question really quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straightforward. Simply create a copy of the longer array, then overwrite elements in this copy with elements from the shorter array.

```
var m = Math.floor(long.length/short.length);

var result = long.slice();
for(var i = 0; i < short.length; ++i) {
    result[i*m] = short[i];
}
```

*Later edit*: Actually, this is wrong. The interesting problem in this question is the spacing algorithm, and you cannot get that by this particular simple multiplication.

I'll leave this answer here anyway, because it might help clarify what this problem is.

Comment: How do you even know that's what OP wants?

Comment: Thank you, give me a few minutes to test it out. Btw, can you please make a running example?

Comment: @thednp - Actually, my answer doesn't work. The problem seems to be one of spacing it out, and my simple multiplication is incorrect. I'll probably delete this.

Comment: Well, it's a good start, don't worry I will "backdoor" protect you :)

Comment: If you replace `floor` with `ceil` it gives the desired result.

Comment: This actually works as expected, it answers my question, we can close it here.

Comment: I think it should be `(long.length-1)/(short.length-1)`